# How to get cell value from expanded gridview row

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

how to get cell value from expanded detail row that is binded to another table?

```
string name = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "colName").ToString())
```

not working because: Column 'colName' does not belong to table 'Users'.

Comment: The error is clear.. `Column 'colName' does not belong to table 'Users'`

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `GetRowCellValue` method with the detail view instead of master view:

```
GridView detailView = gridView1.GetDetailView(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, 0) as GridView;
string name = (string)detailView.GetRowCellValue(detailView.FocusedRowHandle, "colName");
```

Please review the [Navigating Through Master and Detail Rows](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument740) help-article for more details.

Related help article: [Master-Detail Overview](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument783)